Changing classname of "<div data-node-key". No way to get it working
New to JS. I'm trying to change the class of this:
<div data-node-key="holders" class="ant-tabs-tab">
To this:
<div data-node-key="holders" class="ant-tabs-tab ant-tabs-tab-active">
But nothing seems to work since all the tutorials are for query selecting of id's or classes.
I think this code I worked out should do the trick, but I get an error saying:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList') at window.onload
Here's my code:
window.onload = function()
{
        const myElement = document.querySelector('[data-node-key="holders"]')
        console.log(myElement)

        myElement.classList.remove('ant-tabs-tab');
        myElement.classList.add('ant-tabs-tab ant-tabs-tab-active');

        console.log(myElement)
}

I'm injecting this code through a 'custom JS' Chrome extension to modify a website if that's the problem? I can't link you the webpage, because you need to be logged in to see anything, so I've attached a screenshot if that helps.
Screenshot of the HTML
Like I said, I'm new to JS, but I imagine the code gets executed before the page fully loads? Well, I've tried everything I could find and still can't get it to work.
Tried using document.querySelector to select the element and classList.add to add the new class.

the proper syntax is myElement.classList.add('ant-tabs-tab', 'ant-tabs-tab-active');

The problem seems to be that myElement doesn’t exist when window.load runs.  In fact you check that with console.log(myElement).  Is that outputting undefined?

You don't need onload handling if you place your script tag right before the end of the documents' body (so before the closing </body> tag). Furthermore, the way you add classes is not right: the parameters should be one or more class names ('tokens'), separated by comma.
But actually I suppose you want to replace the class? Something like ...


setTimeout(() =>
  document.querySelector(`[data-node-key="holders"]`)
    .classList.replace(
      `ant-tabs-tab`, 
      `ant-tabs-tab-active`), 1500);
.ant-tabs-tab-active {
  color: red;
}

.ant-tabs-tab {
  color: green
}
<div data-node-key="holders" class="ant-tabs-tab">
  active?
</div>



